# Merge tag ansible-2.x with tag ansible?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, tag-synonym-process

Looking at the tags around [ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible) I see no use to have a separate tag [ansible-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible-2.x).

I did not see any question about Ansible 1.x so having both is redundant.

Could it be possible to delete [ansible-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible-2.x) in favor of [ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible) ?

Comment: If people are using [tag:ansible] to mean any version of ansible, yeah, I can see the calling on doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Just based on what's in the wiki for the two tags, [ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible) is the original (1.0) version of the system. At the time the tag was created it was the only version, so no version number was added to the tag.

When Ansible 2.0 was released, a new tag was created, and the old tag left unversioned.

Since they refer to two different *incompatible* product versions, the tags should to stay distinct.

However, a quick look at some recent questions shows some that use both tags, and some that use [ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible) when they should probably be using [ansible-2.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible-2.x). There are probably many old questions that are specific to the 1.x version of Ansible. Therefore, it may make more sense to rename [ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible) to "ansible-1.x" and do a cleanup of existing questions for the correct tag usage. Updating the [ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ansible) wiki to make it clear that it refers specifically to the 1.x product may also be useful.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ansible. This answer is based on the wiki descriptions of the two tags and what I think I've seen other product tags handle versioning.